# how can I split the text in the textarea for each line, and save at database? PHP

Tags: php

I'm using the explode () function to separate the string, but how can I do this for each new line, and how do I save each partition to the database?

---

example textarea string;

john|doe|1994|germany|man

```
$data = $_POST['textarea_data']; 

$parts = explode('|' , $data);

print_r($parts);
```

I can do this separate for only 1 line, how can I do multiple line ? 
john|doe|1994|germany|man 
adam|ray|1992|turkey|man 
jack|doe|1991|switzerland|man 
 like that multiple lines ? and after the seperating i want to save database these parts like that;

name|surname|dob
John  doe          1994
adam  doe          1992
jack  doe          1991

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split multiple lines, use `\n` as per this example for your case:

```
$data = $_POST['textarea_data'];
$lines=explode("\n",$data);
foreach($lines as $data)
{
    $parts = explode('|' , $data);
    print_r($parts);
}
```